# Use linear scales for both the $X-$ and $Y-$ axes?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I am trying to understand this question:

> Use linear scales for both the $X$- and $Y$- axes. In which region, $f_2(x)$
>   is a good approximation to $f_1(x)$?

My equations are: 
$$f_1(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{1+x}}\quad\text{and}\quad
    f_2(x)=1+0.5x-(0.625)x^2+(0.86667)x^3$$
[graph of two functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBqzS.png)
Am I supposed to use:
$$f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x_1-x_0) = 0\Rightarrow
x_1-x_0 = \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}
\Rightarrow x_1 = x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}.$$
How do I find the best region?

Comment: Since the question says what scales to use for the axes, I would assume they want you to draw a graph. Have you done that? As for the equations in $x_0$ and $x_1$, why would you use those?

Comment: Yeah I already drew a graph. I looked up the notes from the professor and he had this and he is using it to approximate the solution of f(x)=0. I guess this is used for the same function and not two different ones?

Comment: Yes, those last set of equations look like one of the ways to find a single $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, applied to a single function. It is a technique for rather a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used Wolfram Alpha to make
[a graph of your two functions.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f1%28x%29%3Dsqrt%28%281%2B2x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%29%3B+f2%28x%29%3D1%2B0.5%2Ax-%280.625%29%2Ax%5E2%2B%280.86667%29%2Ax%5E3)
Here is a version of that graph for $x$ values $-0.5 \leq x \leq 1$:

[image]

Note that $\sqrt{(1+2x)/(1+x)}$ is not even defined for $x < -0.5$,
so there's not much point in looking any further to the left.
But it is *very* important not to just automatically cut off the
entire negative $x$-axis from a graph like this.

Since each function's curve is drawn in a different color, if you place
a vertical straightedge against the graph and compare the $y$-values
at which the two different-colored curves intersect the vertical line,
you will have an idea of how good the approximation is at that point.
Small or no gap is a good approximation, large gap is bad.

Both your graph and the graph above use linear scales for the $y$-axis,
but not the same linear scale; the difference between the two curves
will look smaller on the graph above merely because the scale is smaller.
It is somewhat a matter of judgment to say what approximation is 
"good enough"; I doubt your instructor expects everyone to describe
*exactly* the same region where the approximation is good.
But you can see in either graph that part of the curves of the two 
functions seem to be drawn practically right on top of each other,
which should be a clue.

If you estimate the minimum and maximum "good" $x$ values
by looking at the graph, you can use a calculator to check the values
of the function at those $x$ values to see exactly how small or large
the difference between the functions is.

Comment: thank you and the explanation helped me understand what "good approximation" means